# Obtener el id variable que contiene una etiqueta <a>

Tags: javascript, html5, funciones

Estoy tratando de obtener mediante JS el id que tiene una etiqueta . El id va a ir variando, con lo cual, al hacer onClick debo conocerlo.

```
<a href="#" role="button" onClick="abrirNoticia();" id="id">Título</a>
```

En cuanto a la función estaba utilizando el siguiente código pero la verdad es que ando algo perdido:

```
function abrirNoticia(element){
  var parent = element.parentNode;
  alert(parent.id);
  var content = parent.querySelector("a");
  alert(content.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En su función el problema es que recibe un `undefined` ya que no le envía un valor asociado al parámetro `element`. desde el `HTML` debería pasar `this` que hace referencia al elemento.

```js
function abrirNoticia(element){
  alert(element.id);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" role="button" onClick="abrirNoticia(this);" id="id22">Título</a>
```

Sí desea obtener el `id` de cualquier elemento `a` del documento , puede asignarle el evento a todas las que existan.

```js
var content = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (var i = 0; i <content.length; i++) {
content[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
alert(this.id);
})
}
```

```html
<a href="#" role="button"  id="id">Título</a>
<a href="#" role="button"  id="id1">Título1</a>
<a href="#" role="button"  id="id2">Título2</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Intenta enviando el propio elemento como parametro a la funcion utilizando `this`:

```js
function abrirNoticia(elemento)
{
 alert(elemento.id);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" role="button" onClick="abrirNoticia(this);" id="id-aleatorio">Título</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estoy adivinando que los vínculos se crean dinámicamente en la carga de la página. Hay un par de maneras que usted puede hacer eso. Uno es pasar directamente en el id, 
Como:

```
AbrirNoticia (7)
```

o utilizar "this" como:

`AbrirNoticia (this)` y referenciarlo en el javascript como elemento.id